# How do I extract and process all the files in a zipfile?

Tags: python, data-structures, dataset, zip, python-zipfile

I want to extract and process all the files in a zipped file?

```
import re
import zipfile
import pathlib
import pandas as pd


# Download mHealth dataset
def parse(zip_file):
    # Extract all the files in output directory
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, "r") as zfile:

        for file in zfile.extractall():
            if file.is_file():
                old_name = file.stem
                extension = file.suffix
                directory = file.parent

                new_name = re.sub("mHealth_", "", old_name) + extension
                file = file.rename(pathlib.Path(directory, new_name))
        zfile.close()
        return file
```

Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\project_kmeans.py", line 47,
in <module>
    df_ = parse(zip_file_)   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\project_kmeans.py", line 12,
in parse
    for file in zfile.extractall(): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: error shows you in which line is problem - so use `print()` to see what you have in variables in this line.

Comment: if you use `with open(..) as zfile` then you don't need `close()` because `with .... as ...` will close it automatically.

Comment: did you check `extractall` in documentation?

Comment: `return file` will return only last file. If you want to get all filenames then you should append them to list and return this list.

Answer (score 1):

You need `infolist()` or `namelist()` instead of `extractall()` to work with `for`-loop.

`extractall()` extracts files from `zip` but it doesn't give file names - so it can't be used with `for`-loop.

`infolist()` or `namelist()` gives file names but it makes other problem because it gives object `ZipInfo` or `string`, not `Path`, so it doesn't have `.is_file`, `.stem`, etc. You would have to convert to `Path`.

```
import zipfile
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

# Download mHealth dataset
def parse(zip_file):
    
    results = []
    
    # Extract all the files in output directory
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, "r") as zfile:

        zfile.extractall()  # extract
        
        #for filename in zfile.namelist():
        #    path = pathlib.Path(filename)

        for fileinfo in zfile.infolist():
            filename = fileinfo.filename
            path = pathlib.Path(filename)

            if path.is_file():
                old_name = path.stem
                extension = path.suffix
                directory = path.parent

                new_name = old_name.replace("mHealth_", "") + extension
                path = path.rename(pathlib.Path(directory, new_name))
                print('path:', path)
                results.append([filename, new_name])
                
    df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['old', 'new'])
    return df

df = parse('test.zip')
print(df)
```

---

Doc: [infolist](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist) and [extractall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall)